# Operator Oveloading: "+" and "==" for two classes

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, pointers, overloading

I have one class `Number` (base class) and `two child` class `Fraction` and `Integer`. I am suppose to provide the functionality to `add` and `compare` two Integer obj, two Fraction obj, One Integer One Fraction obj by operator overloading. Below is what I have come up with. Can someone kindly review it. I am trying to avoid memory leaks too. Not sure if I succeeded.

**1. Factory.h**

```
class Factory
{
public:
    Number * createObj(int a);
    Number * createObj(int a, int b);
    Factory(){}

};
```

**2. Factory.cpp**

```
Number * Factory::createObj(int a)
{
    return new Integer(a);

}

Number * Factory::createObj(int a, int b)
{
    return new Fraction(a, b);

}
```

**3. Number.h**

```
class Number
{
public:
    virtual void display(std::ostream &)  = 0;
    virtual Integer * isInteger(){return 0;}
    virtual Fraction * isFraction() { return 0; }
    friend Number* operator+ (Number &, Number &);
    friend bool operator==(Number &, Number &);

};
```

**4. Number.cpp**

```
// overloading "=="
bool operator==(Number &lhs, Number &rhs)
{
    Integer *intPointer1;
    Integer *intPointer2;
    Fraction *fracPointer1;
    Fraction *fracPointer2;
    Display d1;
    Number *sumNumberObj = NULL;
    lhs.display(std::cout);
    d1.printString(" and ");
    rhs.display(std::cout);
    // checking of two integers
    if ((intPointer1 = lhs.isInteger()) && (intPointer2 = rhs.isInteger()))
    {
        if (*intPointer1 == *intPointer2)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    // checking of two fraction
    if (fracPointer1 = lhs.isFraction())
    {
        if (fracPointer2 = rhs.isFraction())
        {
            if (*fracPointer1 == *fracPointer2)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
    // checking of one integer and one fraction
    if (intPointer1 = lhs.isInteger())
    {
        if (fracPointer1 = rhs.isFraction())
        {
            if (*intPointer1 == *fracPointer1)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
    // checking of fraction and integer
    if (fracPointer1 = lhs.isFraction())
    {
        if (intPointer1 = rhs.isInteger())
        {
            if (*fracPointer1 == *intPointer1)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }

}

Number* operator+ (Number &lhs, Number &rhs)
{
    Integer *intPointer1;
    Integer *intPointer2;
    Fraction *fracPointer1;
    Fraction *fracPointer2;
    Display d1;
    Number *sumNumberObj = NULL;
    // addition of two integers
    if (intPointer1 = lhs.isInteger())
    {
        if (intPointer2 = rhs.isInteger())
        {
            sumNumberObj = *intPointer1 + *intPointer2;
            d1.disp(lhs, rhs, *sumNumberObj);
        }
    }
    // addition of two fraction
    if (fracPointer1 = lhs.isFraction())
    {
        if (fracPointer2 = rhs.isFraction())
        {
            sumNumberObj = *fracPointer1 + *fracPointer2;
            d1.disp(lhs, rhs, *sumNumberObj);
        }
    }
    // addition of one integer and one fraction
    if (intPointer1 = lhs.isInteger())
    {
        if (fracPointer1 = rhs.isFraction())
        {
            sumNumberObj = *intPointer1 + *fracPointer1;
            d1.disp(lhs, rhs, *sumNumberObj);
        }
    }
    // addition of fraction and integer
    if (fracPointer1 = lhs.isFraction())
    {
        if (intPointer1 = rhs.isInteger())
        {
            sumNumberObj = *fracPointer1 + *intPointer1;
            d1.disp(lhs, rhs, *sumNumberObj);
        }
    }
    return sumNumberObj;

}
```

**5. Fraction.h**

```
class Fraction : public Number
{
    Integer _numerator;
    Integer _denominator;

public:
    void display(std::ostream &);
    Fraction() {}
    Fraction(const int &, const int &);
    Number* operator+ (const Integer&);
    Number* operator+ (const Fraction&);
    int gcdCalculate(int  val1, int  val2);
    int lcmCalculate(const int  val1, const int  val2);
    bool operator==(const Integer&) const;
    bool operator==(const Fraction&)const;
    Integer getnumerator() const;
    Integer getdenominator()const;
    virtual Fraction * isFraction() { return this; }
     ~Fraction();

};
```

**6. Fraction.cpp**

```
// parameterised constructor 
Fraction::Fraction(const int & num, const int & den)
{
    _numerator.setValue(num);
    _denominator.setValue(den);

}

// destructor
Fraction::~Fraction()
{}

// display the value of number on output console
void Fraction::display(std::ostream & stream)
{
    if (this->_denominator == 0)
        std::cout << "Undefined: " << this->_numerator.getValue() << "/" << this->_denominator.getValue() << " (Divide By Zero Exception)";
    else
        stream << this->_numerator.getValue() << "/" << this->_denominator.getValue();

}

// "+" operator overloading for fraction and fraction
Number* Fraction::operator+ (const Fraction& numberTwo)
{
    int lcm = lcmCalculate(this->_denominator.getValue(), numberTwo._denominator.getValue());
    int multiplier1 = 0;
    if (this->_denominator.getValue())
        multiplier1 = lcm / this->_denominator.getValue();
    int multiplier2 = 0;
    if (numberTwo._denominator.getValue())
        multiplier2 = lcm / numberTwo._denominator.getValue();
    return new Fraction((this->_numerator.getValue() * multiplier1) + (numberTwo._numerator.getValue() * multiplier2), lcm);

}

// "+" operator overloading for fraction and integer
Number* Fraction::operator+(const Integer &secondNumber)
{
    int num = this->getnumerator().getValue();
    int den = this->getdenominator().getValue();
    int numoriginal = secondNumber.getValue();
    int numeratorVal = ((numoriginal * den) + num);
    int denominatorVal = den;
    return new Fraction(numeratorVal, denominatorVal);

}

// LCM Calculation
int Fraction::lcmCalculate(const int  val1, const int  val2)
{
    int temp = gcdCalculate(val1, val2);
    return temp ? (val1 / temp * val2) : 0;

}

// GCD Calculation
int Fraction::gcdCalculate(int val1, int  val2)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        if (val1 == 0) return val2;
        val2 %= val1;
        if (val2 == 0) return val1;
        val1 %= val2;
    }

}

// comparision operator overload for fraction and fraction
bool Fraction::operator==(const Fraction& rhs) const
{
    Integer numCheck = this->_numerator;
    Integer denCheck = this->_denominator;
    if (rhs._numerator.getValue())
        numCheck.setValue(numCheck.getValue() / rhs._numerator.getValue());
    if (rhs._numerator.getValue())
        denCheck.setValue(denCheck.getValue() / rhs._denominator.getValue());
    if (numCheck == denCheck) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

// comparision operator overload for fraction and integer
bool Fraction::operator==(const Integer& rhs) const
{
    int numFrac = this->getnumerator().getValue();
    int denFrac = this->getdenominator().getValue();
    int numVal = rhs.getValue();
    if (denFrac == 0) {
        std::cout << " Error: Undefined Value Undifined(0/0) ";
        return false;
    }
    if (numVal == (numFrac / denFrac))
        return true;
    return false;

}

// getter for numberator
Integer Fraction::getnumerator() const
{
    return this->_numerator;

}

// getter for denominator
Integer Fraction::getdenominator() const
{
    return this->_denominator;

}
```

**7. Integer.h**

```
    class Integer : public Number
    {
        int intValue;

    public:
        void display(std::ostream &);
        int getValue() const;
        void setValue(int);
        Integer() {}
        Integer(int num);
        Number* operator+ (const Integer &);
        Number* operator+ (const Fraction &);
         ~Integer();
        bool operator==(const Fraction &) const;
        bool operator==(const Integer &) const;
        virtual Integer* isInteger() { return this; }

    };
```

**8. Integer.cpp**

```
    // parameterized constructor
    Integer::Integer(int num)
    {
        intValue = num;
    }

    Integer::~Integer()
    {}

    // return integer value

    int Integer::getValue() const
    {
        return this->intValue;
    }

    void Integer::setValue(int x)
    {
        this->intValue = x;
    }

    // operator "+" overloading
     Number* Integer::operator+(const Integer &secondNumber)
    {
        int  temp = this->intValue + secondNumber.intValue;
        return new Integer(temp);

    }

    Number* Integer::operator+( const Fraction& secondNumber)
    {

        int num  = secondNumber.getnumerator().getValue();
        int den = secondNumber.getdenominator().getValue();
        int numoriginal = this->getValue();
        int numeratorVal = ((numoriginal * den) + num);
        int denominatorVal = den;
        return new Fraction(numeratorVal, denominatorVal);

    }

    // operator "=" overloading 
    void Integer::display(std::ostream& stream)
    {
        stream << this->intValue;
    }

    // comparasion operator overload
    bool Integer::operator==(const Fraction& rhs) const
    {
        int numFrac = rhs.getnumerator().getValue();
        int denFrac = rhs.getdenominator().getValue();
        int numVal = this->getValue();
        if (denFrac == 0) {
            std::cout << " Error: Undefined Value Undifined(0/0) ";
            return false;
        }
        if (numVal == (numFrac / denFrac))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    bool Integer::operator==(const Integer& rhs) const
    {
        return this->intValue == rhs.getValue();
    }
```

**9. Display.h**

```
class Display
{
public:
    Display() {}
    void printHeader(const std::string header) const;
    void printString(const std::string str) const;
    void calculateSum(Number&, Number &);
    void disp(Number &, Number &, Number &) const;
    void checkEqual(Number &, Number &) const;
    ~Display() {}

};
```

**10. Display.cpp**

```
// printing header banner to console
void Display::printHeader(const std::string header) const
{
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::string(55, '*') << std::endl <<
        header << std::endl << std::string(55, '*') << std::endl;
}

// prints the string passed to it
void Display::printString(const std::string str) const
{
    std::cout << str;

}

// calling matching "+" overload as per the arguments
void Display::calculateSum(Number &num1, Number &num2)
{
    std::auto_ptr<Number> result (num1 + num2);

}

// displaying appropriate result of returned bool value from "==" overload
void Display::checkEqual(Number &lhs, Number &rhs) const
{
    Display d1;
    if (lhs == rhs)
        d1.printString(" : Numbers are Equal\n");
    else
        d1.printString(" : Numbers are Unequal\n");

}

// displaying the summation on console
void Display::disp(Number &lhs, Number &rhs, Number &sumNumberObj) const
{
    Display d1;
    lhs.display(std::cout);
    d1.printString(" + ");
    rhs.display(std::cout);
    d1.printString(" = ");
    sumNumberObj.display(std::cout);
    d1.printString("\n");

}
```

**11. Main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        Display disp;
        Factory *facObj = new Factory();
        disp.printHeader("TESTING ADDTION OF TWO INTEGERS");
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer1(facObj->createObj(5));
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer2(facObj->createObj(7));
        disp.calculateSum(*numberObjPointer1,  *numberObjPointer2);     
        disp.printHeader("TESTING ADDTION OF TWO FRACTIONS");
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer3(facObj->createObj(1, 5));
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer4(facObj->createObj(1, 7));
        disp.calculateSum(*numberObjPointer3, *numberObjPointer4);
        disp.printHeader("TESTING ADDTION OF INTEGER AND FRACTIONS");
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer5(facObj->createObj(2));
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer6(facObj->createObj(3, 2));
        disp.calculateSum(*numberObjPointer15, *numberObjPointer6);
        disp.printHeader("TESTING ADDTION OF FRACTION AND INTEGER");
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer7 (facObj->createObj(2,5));
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer8 (facObj->createObj(3));
        disp.calculateSum(*numberObjPointer7, *numberObjPointer8);
        disp.printHeader("TESTING EQUALITY OF INTEGER AND INTEGER");
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer9(facObj->createObj(2));
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer10(facObj->createObj(2));
        disp.checkEqual(*numberObjPointer9, *numberObjPointer10);
        disp.printHeader("TESTING EQUALITY OF FRACTIONS");
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer11(facObj->createObj(1,2));
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer12(facObj->createObj(2,2));
        disp.checkEqual(*numberObjPointer11, *numberObjPointer12);
        disp.printHeader("TESTING INTEGER AND FRACTION ARE EQUAL");
        std::auto_ptr <Number> numberObjPointer13 (facObj->createObj(2));
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer14 (facObj->createObj(3, 2));
        disp.checkEqual(*numberObjPointer13, *numberObjPointer14);
        disp.printHeader("TESTING FRACTION AND INTEGER ARE EQUAL");
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer15 (facObj->createObj(1));
        std::auto_ptr<Number> numberObjPointer16 (facObj->createObj(8, 2));
        disp.checkEqual(*numberObjPointer15, *numberObjPointer16);

    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "\n  " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: is `Number.h` compiles? I do not think so

Comment: This question is possibly off topic because the Number.h does not compile on Centos 7 using g++ without the modifications that Nick has suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Code is way too complicated, but let me try:

## Style

you should NOT use names starting with underscore.
I did same error in the near past.

If you want to emphasize that those are `private`,
add the underscore at the end.

## Mixed case file names

You should avoid capital letters in file names. `Windows` and `MacOS` support case insensitive file names, but `Linux` and most `UNIX`-es - do not.

Imagine someone compress the code using `ZIP` or `ARJ` and when you un-compress it - surprise - capital/small letters are lost.

Once I lost all small letters on huge Java project - file names became all-caps - it was easy fixable since all I needed to do is to rename everything with small letters.

Keep class names with capital letter, but make files with small letters. `C++` allow this, `Java` do not.

This is huge problem in `Java` world, but nobody speaking about it.

## Factory.h

no need to provide default c-tor. it can be removed.

## Number.h

I don't think this compiles.

```
virtual Integer * isInteger(){return 0;}
virtual Fraction * isFraction() { return 0; }
```

You need to use `class Integer;` prior `class Number` declaration.

Because you are playing with dynamically allocate objects + polymorphism, you MUST add `virtual d-tor`. I do not think the code will work correctly without it.

```
virtual ~Number(){}
```

I do not like these two:

```
virtual Integer * isInteger(){return 0;}
virtual Fraction * isFraction() { return 0; }
```

Is this conversion or just check if class is Integer / Number?

Naming is unfortunate. Change it it `toInteger()` or change return type to `bool`.

What is `return 0`? If it is a pointer, change it to `return NULL;` or if you are using `C++11` to `return nullptr;`.

## Number.cpp

way too big, skipping for the moment.

## Fraction.h

once again this will not be compilled, because you are using unknown `class Integer`.

`default c-tor` must initialize the `_numerator` and `_denominator`. I suggest following:

```
Fraction() : _numerator(0), _denominator(1)
{}
```

or much better:

```
class Fraction : public Number
{
    Integer _numerator = 0;
    Integer _denominator = 1;
    //...
    Fraction() = default;
```

What is the `d-tor` doing? Is this because of incomplete `class Integer`.

`C++11` comment - remove `virtual`, use `override` or `final`.

`final` helps the optimizer a lot to speed up the code, when class is known.

`division by zero` - I think you need to check somehow for it. Probably in `c-tor`.

## Fraction.cpp

prefer initialize list:

```
Fraction::Fraction(const int & num, const int & den)
{
    _numerator.setValue(num);
    _denominator.setValue(den);
}
```

must be:

```
Fraction::Fraction(const int & num, const int & den) :
                  _numerator(num),
                  _denominator(den)
{
}
```

I would even move it to the `Fraction.h` file.

skipping for now

## Integer.h

same considerations for the `c-tor` and `d-tor`. Initialize the value to zero.
If you do so, you can ommit initialization of `Fraction::_numerator`.

`d-tor` once again doing nothing. this time you can remove it.

## Display.h

remove `c-tor` and `d-tor`.

on all your code, you use `pointers`. now suddenly you switch to `refferences`.
Why? Answer is - to make `main()` more ugly :)

## main()

Do you think there will be exception thrown?

`std::auto_ptr` is deprecated. If you are using `C++11`, change it to `std::unique_ptr`.

Make `std::auto_ptr<Number>` to be `typedef`. You really not need to write it several times.